# Is it cheaper to check if item exists before accessing it on GAE Datastore?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

If I want to load or delete an object from the Datastore. Is it better to check if it exists first? I've read that small operations are free. Does checking for existance save potential read operations to non-existing objects?

```
if (StatusObj.ofy().load().type(Object.class).filterKey(key).count() != 0) {
   StatusObj.ofy().load().key(key).now();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. However, network latency is not negligible and your app's response time will almost double if entities exist.

From: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Batch_operations

A batch operation for two keys costs two reads, even if one of the keys *did not exist*. For example, it is more economical to do a keys-only query that retrieves 1000 keys, and then do a fetch on 500 of them, than to do a regular (not keys-only) query for all 1000 directly:

Query returning 1000 keys + fetching 500 entities:

$0.0000007 (base query cost) + $0.0001 (per-key query cost) + 0.00035 (entity fetch)
= $0.0004507
Fetching 1000 entities:

$0.0000007 (base query cost) + $0.0007 (per-entity query cost)
= $0.0007007

From pricing page (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) :  Small datastore operations include calls to allocate datastore ids or keys-only queries, and these operations are free.

Comment: Thank you, nice to put the calculation there. This is about money after all! :)